# Sending POST parameters with Python using Mechanize

Tags: python, post, upload, mechanize, ambiguity

I want to fill out this form using Python:

```
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="uploadimage">
  <input type="file" name="image" id="image" />
  <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Upload File" class="inputbuttons" />
  <input name="newimage" type="hidden" id="image" value="1" />
  <input name="path" type="hidden" id="imagepath" value="/var/www/httpdocs/images/" />
</form>
```

As you can see, there are two Parameters that are named exactly the same, so when I'm using Mechanize to do it, what would look like this:

```
    import mechanize
    br = mechanize.Browser()
    br.open('www.site.tld/upload.php')
    br.select_form(nr=0)

    br.form['image'] = '/home/user/Desktop/image.jpg'
    br.submit()
```

I am getting the Error:

```
mechanize._form.AmbiguityError: more than one control matching name 'image'
```

Every solution I found in the Internet (including this site) didn't work. Is there a different approach?
Renaming the input in the HTML form is sadly not an option.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You do realize that having two elements with the same id is __illegal__ HTML?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `find_control` instead; you can add a `nr` keyword to select a specific control if there is ambiguity. In your case, the `name` and `type` keywords should do.

Also note that a file control doesn't take a `value`; use `add_file` instead and pass in an open file object:

```
br.form.find_control(name='image', type='file').add_file(
    open('/home/user/Desktop/image.jpg', 'rb'), 'image/jpg', 'image.jpg')
```

See the [documentation on forms in mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/forms.html).